# Display multiple infoboxes within one reactive function in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I wish to know if it is possible to create multiple infoBoxes with only one reactive function "ibox" as in the script below. I shall pass the values for all the infoboxes below within the ibox reactive function and see all of them getting displayed together.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic boxes"),
dashboardSidebar(),
dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
  infoBoxOutput("ibox")
  )))
server <- function(input, output) {
output$ibox <- renderInfoBox({
  infoBox(
    "Title",
    5,
    icon = icon("credit-card")
  )
  infoBox(
    "Title",
    5,
    icon = icon("credit-card")
  )
  infoBox(
    "Title",
    4,
    icon = icon("credit-card")
  )

  })}
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Look at `renderUI()` and `uiOutput()` instead:) I think if you replace `renderInfoBox()` with `renderUI()` you should already be fairly close to what you want.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, Still getting the same thing, if you can help me with a working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you could use `renderUI` and `uiOutput`. However, note that `renderUI` only actually renders the last statement in its body. In order to render multiple objects, we can place them in a list (or `column`, `fluidRow`, etc.). Working example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic boxes"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      uiOutput("ibox")
    )))
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$ibox <- renderUI({
    list(
      infoBox(
        "Title",
        5,
        icon = icon("credit-card")
      ),
      infoBox(
        "Title",
        5,
        icon = icon("credit-card")
      ),
      infoBox(
        "Title",
        4,
        icon = icon("credit-card")
      )
    )
  })}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```